# Changing variable values from external files in XNA 4.0

Tags: c#, xna, xna-4.0

What is the easiest way to change the value of a variable in a XNA 4.0 game?

I have a few objects that I want to be able to show/hide (as a programmer not as a user) without rebuilding the game itself. I was trying to do this with XML but it proved to be to advanced for my level of knowledge of XNA. My idea is to have a file that will have a simple structure (name_of_variable1, value_of_variable1, name_of_variable2, value_of_variable2...). Since there is a limited number of variables that I need to change (4 or 5 `bool` variables - I can hold my drawing methods inside `if-else` statements and then control their execution with these `bool` variables); these file(s) will be standardized.

What I want to accomplish is this: when I publish my program, I want to have a file in it's "Content" folder that I can change in any text editor and when I start my program, it reads that file and sets the values of these variables accordingly (there will be only one file, that I will overwrite when necessary).

What is the simplest way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: I think you're probably better off just using the standard XML stuff rather than writing your own way of doing it. It achieves the same thing basically. The difference is that the names aren't included, so you have to read the data in the same order it was written.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend using CSV, XML or INI file formats, depending on the type of data you want stored.

CSV is great for data in which you have a header, and lots of records of that data, like say Sprite_sheets.csv could contain headers ID, PATH, WIDTH, HEIGHT, and rows of sprite sheets that you use.

INI is great for single settings variables, like FPS=60, FULLSCREEN=true, etc.

XML is great for greater data structures, like  your MAP, which contains TILES, OBJECTS, SPRITES inside, and those contain some other objects, etc.

I usually just use CSV, and I found this really great C# CSV reader/writer:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/86973/C-CSV-Reader-and-Writer

But you could use whatever works for you.

Comment: I managed to solve this problem, but now I have another one (that builds on this one). I have posted the question about it at this address: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/22636/nullreferenceexception-problem-when-loading-savegame-in-xna-4-0. There are 2 answers. but I haven't been able to get it to work, so if you could take a look and give me your opinion, I'd be very grateful. Thanks